# XPath to select all attributes and values

Tags: xpath

I'm working with some XML that keeps all its data in attributes. I'm needing to extract that for processing the data. So we have something like:

```
<data>
  <level1>
    <level2 att1="1">
      <level 3>
        <level 4 att2="a" att3="b" att4="c" />
      </level 3>
      <level 3>
        <level 4 att2="1" att3="2" att4="3" />
      </level 3>
    </level 2>
    <level 2 att1="2">
```

So i'm wanting all attributes from the level 4 entries and their values, but ONLY from level2 entries where att1 = 1. I'm new to XPath, so I haven't worked it out yet. So far, the best I've come up with is:

```
/data/level1/level2[@att1='1']/level3/level4[@*]
```

but that is returning empty data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all the desired attribute values, you only have to make a little change to your XPath expression like this (remove the last predicate to directly access the attributes):

```
/data/level1/level2[@att1='1']/level3/level4/@*
```

Iterating over this expression's nodeset gives you all the desired values and, if wanted, their attribute's names.

Comment: That got it. Thank you. One quick addition, how would I pull the attribute names along with the values?

Comment: In the loop iterating over the result of the above expression, I used `concat(local-name(),' - ',.,'&#xa;')`. This gives `name - value` pairs, for example. So generally, use `concat` with `local-name()`.

Comment: Apparently Google Sheets doesn't like that at all. Probably something with how it handles the results.

Comment: I don't know about Google Sheets, but it is the correct XPath way. To concatenate both values in one expression, XPath 2.0 is needed. Then you could use `/data/level1/level2[@att1='1']/level3/level4/@*/concat(local-name(),' - ',.)`.